# Conversation.Id is unique? ServiceUrl has changed?

Tags: botframework

I used Conversation.Id + ServiceUrl as unique id of Conversation id for many channels (Skype, Telegram, FaceBook). After last botframework update (I think) ServiceUrl changed from  https://skype.botframework.com to https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/

What I can use as unique conversation id for all channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems it changed some time ago per these threads ([#1](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1955), [#2](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2003), [#3](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2037)). I think you should be able to use Conversation.Id + [activity.ChannelId](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/a71e64c24bd40f8b99de0a3326ea1b79110c33e1/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Shared/IActivity.cs#L39).

Answer (score 1):

`Conversation.Id` + `serviceUrl` is quite danger combination.
In official [documentation](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/routing.html) it's said that we should not rely on them as in case of `serviceUrl`:

[image]
and `Conversation.Id` is unique per channel as is stated [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/core-concepts/reference/#conversation-object):
[image]

Consider using these combinations which are unique:

`activity.ChannelId + activity.From.Id` - for [saving](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/stateapi.html) user data
`conversation.Id + activity.ChannelId` - for saving channel data